# AsyncHttpClient doesn't use the HTTPS port set in the constructor

Tags: android, asynchttpclient

I'm trying to change the port I'm using for HTTPS connection between my Android client and my server, but the port doesn't get set for some reason. I initialize the HTTP client like this:

```
// Use port 8185 for HTTPS
client = new AsyncHttpClient(80, 8185);
```

... but I get an Exception:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://192.168.1.35 refused
...
Cause by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.35 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Based on these errors, it seems that the default port 443 is still being used. Why is that? Why can't I use the non-default port 8185?

Edit: [This](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) is the library I'm using.

Comment: Is this the library you're using? https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

Comment: It's worth mentioning that on the question.

Comment: you should use this AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(80, 443);

Comment: @dhams Why? I want to use the port 8185, not 443.

Comment: Not sure this Lib having support of TCP

Comment: @dhams It's a HTTP library. It's on a different network layer.

Comment: @manabreak Try the answer I've given. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read in the [Javadocs](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.ning/async-http-client/1.9.27) and on the lib [website](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), perhaps you could try something like:

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig cf = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setProxyServer(new ProxyServer(ProxyServer.Protocol.HTTPS,"IP_ADDRESS", 8185)).build();
AsyncHttpClient c = new AsyncHttpClient(cf);
```

Comment: Actually, it seems that this is a different library than the one I'm using. I mistakenly interpreted the link you posted in the comments as the library I'm using.

Comment: Oh. Then can you please post the link for the lib you're using?